# Workorder management with DDD and ORM

Tags: domain-driven-design

The central tenet to the software I am building is the "workorder"

WorkOrder as I see it would be an ***"aggregate root"*** that contains basic information about the work order such as creation date, model/manufacturer, serial number, purchase order.

In addition to these ***"value"*** objects, there are also sub ***"entities"*** or ***"aggregates"*** such as:

- Sequences
- Reworks
- Dimensions
- QuoteItems
- Consumables

None of the above can/should exist without an associated work order. In the existing system they actually occasionally do but that is because of lack of transactions or checks in code to ensure integrity. They are orphaned records and deleted via scheduled clean up - one of the many reasons I am learning more about DDD and ORM to bring our development practices up to speed.

> NOTE: This is probably off topic and can likely be skipped in your
>   reply
>
> because we are primarily a web-based interface using extJS, each of
>   the list controls that display each of the above, I have been
>   reluctant to switch to ORM and DDD. Each list is populated via a
>   controller:action that queries the DB (ie: sequences list is populated
>   when the JS control calls a sequence REST URI with GET command). This
>   GET command invokes a controller that instantiates a sequence object
>   and calls the *selectAllForWorkorderID* method
>
> My understanding of ORM is that I would use a repository to query
>   these items. Fine, however if this sequence object (in DDD parlance)
>   is considered an aggregate of WorkOrder root - then I must find the
>   workorder first and traverse the sequences through the WorkOrder.
>
> In a AJAX web-based context this feels funny to me - but in a desktop
>   environment or even standard web-based context this is acceptable as I
>   would only query the WorkOrder object once each time a WorkOrder item
>   is selected in the master list. Not 6 or 8 times for each individual
>   list to be populated.

I can see now that our system actually has several aggregate root objects, work order is just the more complicated of the few:

1. WorkOrder
2. Warranties
3. Repair Orders

Are the primary roots. Warranties are dependent on work order ID's and Repair Orders can be but not always.

Ignoring the latter roots - allow me to focus solely on WorkOrder.

When I begin examine the existing models and try to determine what is business logic and/or application logic I am slightly confused. What goes into a ***"service"*** versus ***"aggregate root"***.

Consider one such method in the current model:

createWorkOrderFromRpi.

RPI's are approved documents that act as templates for WorkOrders - they dictate what sequences and the order of execution "can" be performed, dimensions, list of consumables etc. This is a separate system altogether and I believe would best be described as a ***"module"*** in DDD nomenclature.

This method has to query the RPI system and obtain the work order header details, sequence list, consumables, etc.

Once it has this data it calls the associated objects and methods:

1. WorkOrder.Create(Header Details)
2. Sequence.Create(Sequence Details) - Done in loop (1:m)
3. Consumable.Create(Consumable Details) - Done in loop (1:m)

In following DDD I am tempted to have the WorkOrder ***"aggregate root"*** provide a method with an identical signature however I am reluctant to do so.

I believe each of the "***entities"*** that are aggregates of WorkOrder fit the description and should not ever be exposed to anything outside of the "***root"*** unless traversed through the root itself. There may be cases where this is not the case. On second thought, the interface only ever exposes consumables and sequences and such when a work order is selected which would imply a work order must be loaded anyway?!?

There are some essential business rules which this method must perform:

1. A Work order with identical serial number is not actively already in the system (unless archived) unless it's on sub-contract in which case do not create a new work but receive a repair order for this work order instead.

There are a few more ***"rules"*** but I will exclude them for the sake of brevity.

The individual entities perform micro business validations, for example some fields, such as serial number, have a specific format, as do part numbers and purchase order numbers.

My primary question or concern, is given the above description, would this method best be implemented in an ***"aggregate root"*** or ***"service"***?

UPDATE | One final question...if aggregate root is the proper concept...and I need access to the sequences so that I may update a field I would access conceptually (ignore syntax) like:

WorkOrder.Sequences(0).moveToNext()

If this method was implemented in the sequences ***"entity"*** which makes sense. Where does the division between technical details and business logic exist? For example, to move a work order from one sequence to the next, we update three timestamps per sequence:

date_entered
date_started
date_finished

When the last timestamp is set, the next sequence date_entered is set to the same time as previous sequence date_finished and the system knows this is the active sequence now. Thats a technical matter.

But a business rule or constraint would be:

1. Don't move work order if moved into history
2. Don't move work order if in rework
3. Don't move work order if in subcon

These are rules, which I would love to keep separated and distinct so as to make it easy for me to translate into English in the form of a specs document which I could present management as a living document and proof of functionality. I was kind of hoping that is what DDD would enforce/promote in a clean manner. Is this a requirement handled independently of DDD? Is this where CQS comes in? Separating business rules from technical matters which are of zero relevance to stake holders?

Alex

Answer (score 0):

I think your createWorkOrderFromRpi() method should be on a "Service" rather than the WorkOrder aggregate root. This service method would then call methods on your Repositories or DAOs to create the workorder. An Aggregate Root typically combines entities but on your model I think RPI is a template or specification outside of the work order aggregate root. If RPI is part of the aggregate then you should put the method on the repository directly and call it wherever, as a repository is a business object in DDD also.

On the second question I believe a WorkOrder Aggregate Root is totally correct for the other "dependent" entities you listed, namely
    Sequences
    Reworks
    Dimensions
    QuoteItems
    Consumables

I'm interested to know how you implemented this.